# How to scrub code before running on my server? (node.js)

Tags: node.js, security, code-injection

Someone wants to run node.js code on my server, but I get to look at it first and then decide if it's OK. What program/tool can I use to check that their code does nothing "dangerous" and doesn't have network access.

I'm OK w/ the tool being more aggressive (ie, reports safe code as dangerous) as opposed to too lax (ie, reporting dangerous code as safe).

I can think of a few ways to do this myself (all ugly), but I'm sure this is a common problem and that "safe code checker"s have been invented for most/all languages.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious question here is: Which actions do you consider dangerous? Executing arbitrary code? Generating significant load (if yes: Which kind of load)?

I'm not aware of any suitable scanners for dangerous behavior - doing this statically (i.e. without executing) would be kind of complicated due to bazillions of ways for obfuscating such behavior and the need for heuristics detecting these. Common scanners like nsp and snyk just scan for known vulnerabilites in your dependencies, but do not scan your code for suspicious behavior. Node does not provide functionality to disable specific functions like, for instance, PHP does.
Especially if you considere resource usage an issue any scanner is out of question anyways.

You could restrict the node process via means of your host operating system: chrooting the application, configuring your firewall to drop all traffic from the application's user group and so on. Another way would be running the potentially suspicious application in a docker container, without exposing the Docker socket and by configuring proper [ulimits](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ulimit.3.html) to avoid stuff like file descriptor exhaustion of the shared kernel. Setting up [SELinux](https://github.com/SELinuxProject) is another layer that you could add here.

Another option, and probably the easiest to setup securely, is running the Node application inside a VM, and not attaching any network device to that VM. At worst, that application could screw up the OS inside the VM. Just make sure you configure resource limits via limiting CPU and RAM usage of the VM and keep the virtualizer/hypervisor updated. There is still the risk of the node application escaping the VM via a 0-day vulnerability like the [floppy driver screw up](https://venom.crowdstrike.com/) we saw a few years ago, but the VM route still appears to be the most secure option you have.